# Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

This error just started to popup.  Is it a bug or an update?

```
Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:': 'void (^ _Nonnull __strong)(void)' vs 'void (^__strong _Nonnull)()'
```

**My Code**

```
// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
```

**Previous Definition (Their Code)**

```
// The method will be called on the delegate when the user responded to the notification by opening the application, dismissing the notification or choosing a UNNotificationAction. The delegate must be set before the application returns from application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler __IOS_AVAILABLE(10.0) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(3.0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

Comment: I am seeing the same statement as a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I changed it to:

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center 
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response 
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler;
```

and now the warning is gone.

Answer (score 1):

For you information, from https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78855:

> same. But following the spec at this link, I added "void" in the empty
>   parentheses and it was happy
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html
>
> (void (^)(void))completionHandler...